# Formula to Extract from Column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a simple column with the file name, [Name]. 
Within our file name we include a revision, always worded "Rev0X" where X is next appropriate number.

So sample file name would be "C081-02-003 - Rev01 - Document Title"

I am looking to create a custom column that extracts the Rev number, but do not know where to start with a formula.

Essentially the new column, based on above sample file name, would return "01" but would be capable of adapting based on documents that could have any Rev number from 00 to 99.

Comment: Thank you. How do i add this such that it outputs the RevXX validation into a new column?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column of the type `Calculated (calculation based on other columns)` and use the following formula (in my example I'm using the Title field as the field that contains the file name, but you can change it to your field name):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Rev",[Title])),"",MID([Title], FIND("Rev",[Title])+3,2))
```

Here you can find more about used formulas:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-function-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665